# Для каждого торгового предложения уникальная ссылка(Bitrix)

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

При выгрузке каталога в Яндекс, вылилась ошибка что для каждого SKU нужна уникальная ссылка, при переходе по которой будет сразу активным торговое предложение. Т.к. шаблон индивидуальный то решения которые есть на форуме Bitrix не помогает. Есть ссылка к примеру магазин.ру/машина но у этой машины есть свойства (красная, зеленая, синяя) и каждое свойство имеет свой ид.  Мне нужно чтобы при переходе по ссылке магазин.ру/машина/?pid=111     знатоки Битрикса меня поймут. Я нашел кусок кода который отвечает за все эти действия, но ничего не получается. 
Вот кусок кода модуля

```
 <div class="offers">
                            <ul class="offer-list">
                                <? foreach ($arResult['OFFERS'] as $iKey => $arOffer): ?>
                                    <li data-id="<?= $arOffer['ID']; ?>"<?= ($iKey == 0) ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>>
                                        <? if ($arOffer['PRICES'][$sPriceCode]['CAN_BUY'] == 'Y' && $arOffer['CATALOG_AVAILABLE'] == 'Y'): ?>
                                            <span><?= $arOffer['PRICES'][$sPriceCode]['PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE']; ?></span>
                                        <? endif; ?>
                                        <?= $arOffer['NAME']; ?>
                                    </li>
                                <? endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <?$this->setFrameMode(true);?>
                    </div>
```

Вот кусок кода скрипт js который отвечает за выбор SKU

```js
    var offers = $('.b-element .offer-list li');

    offers.on('click', function(){
        var element = $(this).closest('.b-buy'),
            id = $(this).data('id');

        offers.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.offer', element).hide().removeClass('active');
        $('.offer-' + id, element).show();
    });
});
```

Пытался сделать как-то так

```js
    var offers = $('.b-element .offer-list li');

    offers.on('click', function(){
        var element = $(this).closest('.b-buy'),
            id = $(this).data('id');

        offers.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        loc = '?pid=' + this.offers[this.offerNum].ID;
        history.pushState({}, '', loc);
        $('.offer', element).hide().removeClass('active');
        $('.offer-' + id, element).show();
    });
});
```

Но ничего не выходит, на форуме Битрикса есть решения для стандартного шаблона и выглядит оно так

```js
{
   var i = 0,
      j = 0,
      strName = '',
      arShowValues = false,
      arCanBuyValues = [],
      arFilter = {},
      tmpFilter = [],
      current = this.offers[this.offerNum].TREE,
   //CUSTOM START
      paramsUrl = window.location.search,
      pidRegExp = new RegExp(/[?&]pid=(\d+)/),
      pid = pidRegExp.exec(paramsUrl);
      

   if (pid && pid[1]) {
      for (i = 0; i < this.offers.length; i++)
      {
         if (this.offers[i].ID == pid[1]) {
            current = this.offers[i].TREE;
         }
      }  
   }
   //CUSTOM END
```

Но как переписать его под мои нужды знаний не хватает, может кто что подскажет буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо зайти в настройку компонента и во вкладках:
Основные параметры - Инфоблок записать что-то вроде **BLOCK_ID**
Управление адресами страниц - Идентификатор элемента записать **ELEMENT_ID**

И когда вы будите обращаться к каталогу, в параметрах передаете свои значения, 
 например:

```
магазин.ру/машина/?ELEMENT_ID=111&BLOCK_ID=3
ELEMENT_ID=111 - Элемент каталога
BLOCK_ID=3  - Инфоблок каталога
```

Шаблонны генерации ссылок задаются в настройке инфоблока на первой вкладке.

Этот прием сработает без кастомизации компонента.
Но я бы предпочел вариант с доработкой компонента.

Comment: все верно, но мне ссылка нужна не на каталог или элемент, а на торговое предложение элемента (sku). Это разные вещи, и на торговые предложения ссылки не задаются через настройку компонента

Comment: я описал вам алгоритм, при котором можно задать ссылки на торговые предложения

Comment: вы описали алгоритм как задать ссылки на каталоги и элементы т.к. свойство BLOCK отвечает за каталоги а свойство ELEMENT отвечает не посредственно уже за сам элемент но ни как не торговое предложение данного элемента.

Comment: так можно сделать и для торгового предложения